# GA showing (not set) for Google Ads campaigns

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

I am seeing something absolutely crazy in my GA. I have a Google Ads account which is properly linked to my GA. Auto-tagging is also enabled. I have one Search and one Display campaign. But when I look at the reports in GA, this is what I see:

[image]

As you can see GA correctly records the clicks as coming from the the campaigns but then there is this (not set) campaign which is receiving all the users. The the Search and Diplay campaigns have no users respectively. This is the only landing page of the campaigns:

https://www.devimax.com/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8

All the standard articles and answers why you might be getting (not set) talk about linking your Adwords account to GA and enabling auto tagging. But this is all done.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

Bizarrely when you create and ad in Google Ads, if you do not prefix the destination url with http or https, your ad link in the search results will hit http first.

The ad link points to the Google aclk url for your ad which redirect to your destination url. But when you hover over the ad link in the search results it shows https://storeurl.com in the browser status bar because the link has a data-preconnect-urls to https://storeurl.com.

But in reality it hits http. My website is configured to redirect from http to https and this was causing the Google Ads tracking to lose the session and record only the visit under the campaign but not the transaction.

So you should always prefix your ads destination urls with https.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the GA admin page, then click on the eCommerce setting, if it is not enabled then click turn ON.
2. Set `UTM Code` in Google Adwords - In the left corner, click on the setting, then go to the account setting, you will see a tracking code option if the code is not set then paste this code -

> {lpurl}?utm_campaign={campaignid}&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content={creative}&utm_term={keyword}&adgroupid={adgroupid}

then save it. 
It's Done. Please, give feedback to us after applying all setting.